# A/V port on screen use with Pi A/V port

Tags: pi-2, screen, setup

I was thinking about getting [this screen](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/60-10345) because I want as few wires as possible.  Would I be able to plug a 3.5mm cable between a **Pi 2** and the A/V port on the front of the screen and transmit video? Also, for A/V cable would have to be with four rings right?

Comment: Yes, four rings it is. (And nobody complains about the amount of questions ;) just notice that I did not understand the difference between two of them).

Comment: Hello NULL, did you find out any details about this screen and its connections? Please feel free to share your experience by writing your own answer and/or consider voting/accepting the existing answers.

Comment: Be aware that the (analogue) image cannot be as sharp or well defined as a HDMI (digital) one.  The documentation for this unit (Pyle's Part PLHR76) is a little short on details - it *may* have stereo audio but the number of RCA connectors seem to discount this - the similar "PLHR77" model compared to this does have the stereo audio and a second RCA video input for about the same price at the time I looked.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [product description](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/content/ProductData/Manuals/60-10345.pdf) there is a wire connected to the screen with a red RCA jack (for right audio) and a yellow RCA jack (for composite video). The front A/V 3.5 mm input jack is unfortunately not described in further detail. It could be a four contact jack or just three contacts (as the wiring suggests mono audio only).

But (as desired) to keep wires to a minimum I would suggest to get an adaptor cable four ring 3.5 mm jack A/V to three separate RCA connectors. Plug those to the wire of the screen and be done (no additional wiring on the front of the screen).